# Why is there no way to return typed groups in a regular expression matcher?

Tags: java, regex

I've just finished reviewing some code, which was a regular expression that 'parsed', in the loosest sense of the word, a fair few numbers from a string.

Simple example being:

```
^([0-9]{1}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{1}) .... and so on$
```

Which should match '3 4 5 ..... and so on', if I'm not mistaken.

It seemed like, due to the amount of numbers that were being checked in the string and how complex the string was in the case I'm referring to, that indeed a regular expression was potentially the right way to go about matching but when trying to extract the numbers, the author of the code was having to do a fair few calls to the following method with the matcher group: -

```
Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(index))
```

If a regular expression engine is explicitly being told to capture a group that contains only 0-9 {1-2}, is there no way to explicitly capture the correct type so as not to parse again? In this case, should the pattern be matched without using a regular expression, depending upon how complex the pattern is? Perhaps my understanding of how a regular expression group matcher works is not complete.

Do other languages support this?

*I suppose implementing a light weight parseInt without the error checking branches would be a slight performance improvement if I were so inclined to 'squeeze' out that last bit of performance. Looking at the parseInt method, there's a fair few branches for error checking that might not be needed after a regex match*

Comment: This is just how the matcher works. Sting in - strings out. Take it or parse it.

Comment: You could wrap the matcher in an object that does the parsing for you if you don't like calling Integer.parseInt all over the place

Comment: or build your own fluent type safe regex matcher, which is able to also extract the single groups accordingly ;-)

Comment: Also; how could this be statically typed. You're suggesting that the regex engine should examine the string passed to it at compile time (even though it's passed at runtime) and provide a group method that''s only available for indexes that are numbers (even though java  doesn't do that). You could make that work if regexes were a part of the language and considerably different from how regexes work now

Comment: Of course a groupInt method that just assumes it's an int would be fine and easy, but that's not examining the pattern as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

A routine or class that can do everything you want can be pleasant to use, but it is difficult to maintain or to use flexibly. The design issue here is *separation of concerns*, the principle that information that can change independently should be separated within the program.

The concern of the regular expression parser is to identify sections of an input string to elements of an expected pattern. Converting those string sections to other java data types is a separate concern. Sure, a Group matching `([0-9]*)` is *likely* (but not certain) to be best represented in a numeric type, but which numeric type? The type conversion can be done separately.

Within your program design, you are likely to be converting the input string to some complex data type. You can encapsulate that in a single class or method, so that for the rest of your program it is a single step. But it's not practical for the java platform to anticipate your requirements sufficiently to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Deciding the appropriate type for what you match is part of lexical analysis (one of the first steps towards creating a compiler), and it's not a job for the regular expression engine. Tools that do lexical analysis are called lexers or tokenizers.

If you want to do lexical analysis, you have a [`StreamTokenizer` in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) but it's quite limited. If I needed a lexer I would use [JFlex](http://www.jflex.de/) or something similar, or roll my own, depending on the project.